# Deposit to Binance does not appear in wallet. Does anybody have an idea?

Tags: transactions

I am facing problems with a deposit to Binance. The funds have been transferred from a Tezos wallet within the Tezos network. The transactions hash show that the transaction was a success but the funds do not show up. Binance says that there is a maintenance issues on the Tezos side.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the transaction was successful (as seen on public block explorers like tzkt and tzstats) AND it is not showing up in your Binance balance, then the issue is 100% within Binance's domain and only Binance can resolve the issue.

"there is a maintenance issues on the Tezos side" could be referencing an internal Binance issue as there is no maintenance going on the tezos network right now. There is only ever "maintenance" on the network during protocol upgrades which only happen every 4-6 months.